# SQL Server Rebuilding Indexes Not Responding

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index

Just a quick question.

I am currently rebuilding indexes of my hotel front office system.
I have 1 table with huge amount of data.
I clicked Rebuild All on indexes. It was running fine up to the 3rd index.
I accidentally clicked on the Title Bar of the SQL where it states "Rebuild Indexes" , now it states "Rebuild Indexes ( Not Responding )".

Is it ok if i just leave it?
OR
Do i need to end task? If i end task/process by Task Manager , will i lose data?

Urgent Help.

Comment: Let it run.  If you want to know how far along it is, open up another instance of SSMS and connect to the server, then run a query against the [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177648.aspx) to see how much longer your query has to finish.  Since you issued a **REBUILD** and not a REORG, cancelling the query will result in a rollback which will take even more time.  Just tough it out if you can.

Comment: Hi @JohnEisbrener - i open up resource monitor on the server and checked if there is still disk activity. Currently it is running at 100MB/sec , Read is between 25 to 40Million Bytes per second , while Write is between 2 to 5 million Bytes per second. So im leaving it as it is. Hopefully not more than 30 minutes. System need to be up in another 30 minutes. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @JohnEisbrener - Rebuild indexes return to normal , and now it is at Executing. Might take some time due to really huge table transaction.

Its a 3years transactions and none of the old data i ever move to archive database.

Comment: Perform index maintenance off-hours going forward.  Don't put yourself in a situation where you may be get into trouble for good intentions.

Comment: Well , im doing this since 2am. Night audit was done by front office at 1.30.

It is now 4.30am.. and im still not done.. hahahahaha... They need the system at 5am..